# Jquery edit multiple children at once during clone

Tags: jquery, clone

I am currently using the following code.  Which clone an element and changed an input in the clone to what I need it to be.  There is a select in the clone as well that I need to change it's name to another val.  How do I execute 2 children on the same clone command at the same time?

Code:

```
$(this).parent().parent()
    .append($(this).parent()
    .clone()
    .children('input').attr('name', VAL)
    .end()
);
```

I need something like this

```
$(this).parent().parent()
    .append($(this).parent()
    .clone()
    .children('input').attr('name', VAL)
    .children('select').attr('name', VAL2) // Where this does not target children of the input, but of the clone.
    .end()
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is with some thanks to gdoron, but he refused to change his answer to the actual correct answer.  If you need to edit multiple children in a clone or in any object simple use end and specify the next child.

```
$(this).parent().parent()
    .append($(this).parent()
    .clone()
    .children('input').attr('name', VAL)
        .end()
    .children('select').attr('name', VAL2) 
        .end()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().parent()
    .append($(this).parent()
    .clone()
    .children('input, select').attr('name', VAL)
);
```

Or:

```
$(this).parent().parent()
    .append($(this).parent()
    .clone()
    .children('input').attr('name', VAL)
    .end()
    .children('select').attr('name', OtherVal) 
);
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qJzLp/)

Comment: Does the `.end` in 2nd version goes to the original element or the clone?

Comment: @Vega, the cloned, why would it go to the original element?

Comment: I tried this and it failed.  It only clones the select when this method is used (code following the OR)

Comment: @Iscariot, see the Demo I added,

Comment: The problem with your OR answer and how its differs from your demo is it needs an .end() after the second children.  By doing that it is correct.

Comment: @Iscariot, well.. it depends on what you're trying to do, in the DEMO I append the result, so I needed the second `end`. BTW, I think `end` is not readable and should be avoided, my personal opinion.